# Author(s) per chapter - short story collection

Tags: packages, sectioning, memoir, chapters

I'm trying to use LaTeX to typeset a collection of short stories.  I need something that lets each chapter have its own author or authors, with the author name(s) listed along with the chapter title, in the table of contents, and possibly also in running heads (I haven't decided yet how fancy I want to make the running heads).  I'm not having any luck finding something that does this in CTAN, can anyone recommend anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly (I haven't tried it myself) you can use memoir and `\chapterprecis`:

From 6.5.8 of the [memoir manual](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf):

> The command `\chapterprecis` prints its
>   argument both at the point in the
>   document where it is called, and also
>   adds it to the .toc ﬁle. For example:
>
> ```
> ...
> \chapter{}% first chapter
> \chapterprecis{Our hero is introduced; family tree; early days.}
> ...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> \chapterprecishere{<text>}
> \chapterprecistoc{<text>}
> ```
>
> The `\chapterprecis` command calls these two
>   commands to print the `<text>` in the
>   document (the `\chapterprecishere`
>   command) and to put it into the ToC
>   (the `\chapterprecistoc` command). These
>   can be used individually if required.

It also has commands to alter the font and style used for `\chapterprecis`.

Comment: Isn't that an abuse of one semantic notation for a different purpose?  What if you want to have both author and precis?

Comment: sure, but it is possibly a practical solution.  Perfect, certainly not.  Perhaps,  having a look how memoir implements it may at least make it easier to implement \chapterauthor in the same fashion?

Comment: will "\def\chapterauthor\chapterprecis" make it semantic enough? ;)

Comment: I sort of *do* want to have both an author and a precis; it's complicated, though, I should probably ask a new question about that.  This works well enough for now.  Thanks.